# How should one bundle JS in an ASP.NET MVC4 partial view that is returned via AJAX?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using the System.Web.Optimization framework to bundle and minify my JavaScript and I'm using the @section Script{ } sections to ensure all my JavaScript is defined at the bottom of the page.  This includes resources such as the jQuery stuff.

Now, one of my pages has an AJAX function.  When this function returns it returns a Partial View which is then added to the DOM.  This Partial view contains a form and some JavaScript that wires up event handlers for elements within the partial view using (unsurprisingly) jQuery.

Now, I currently have this JavaScript declared in the page within script tags, but I'm trying to move to a situation where all my JavaScript is unobtrusive (in other words, all in external files).

Normally with a Partial, I would ensure that the external JS file is defined in the bundle on the parent View, but this is AJAX, so the $(document).ready(...) will fire BEFORE my AJAX returns.

I'm exploring the jQuery's .on() method [which seems to have replaced the deprecated .live() method], but is this the best approach or are there others I should consider?

Thanks in advance

Griff

Answer (score 0):

I have done this 2 different ways.  The first was to put my click events and such into a function that I called after the partial view has loaded.  This made the code available and would run on the partial view.  The second way that I learned recently was to write my events a little differently

```
$(document).on('click', '.btnSubmit', function(){
    //code
});
```

Writing the event this way it will fire even with the partial view loaded after the page is loaded.  Hopefully this helps.